# Where is DataFrame() after moving from panda.io.data to pandas_datareader?

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

installed python/pandas in a new PC,
Successfully installed pandas-datareader-0.2.1 requests-file-1.4.1
But the old code is not working after replacing pandas.io with pandas_datareader.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)

columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'DateIdx']
diDian = web.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

Get this,
  File "delme1.py", line 9, in 
    diDian = web.DataFrame(columns=columns)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

How to fix this please ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You already have a dataframe from `f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)`.

Comment: @Abdou You are right, i need time to get familiar with the new style.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this works

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)

f['DateIdx'] = 0

columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'DateIdx']
diDian = f[columns]
```